# C++ template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, assign

I have a template that makes a vector. The default constructor assigns n identical valued elements.  The second constructor makes a vector with given arguments. Due to the fact that the second constructor uses the default constructor to define the vector, I can only give arguments about how many elements will be in this vector and what is their value.

```
    public:
      vector<float> coords;
      Vector<n> (){
      coords.assign(n, 0.0);
      }
      Vector<n> (vector<float> crds){
          coords.assign(crds.size(),0.0);
}
```

Ideally the second constructor should take *crds* and check it size. Then assign zeros as many times as the size of *crds*. It works well if the size is 2. But if the size is more or less than 2 it gives out errors.

If I get this working then I would insert every value in crds and pop the unnecessary zeros. But at the moment I can't figure out another solution. + I didn't find any other vector stl function that would suit me better than assign.

The code with which I check the result is

```
    Vector<2> v2 (vector<float>(2,3));
```

Comment: It seems that you want to implement a fixed size Vector type (have you considered `std::array`?) but want to initialize it with a variable sized vector. What are you going to do when the sizes don't match? Depending on the answer to that question, the options will differ.

Comment: It's a silly design. If you always want N zeroes, then what do you need that other std::vector for? Also, use Eigen. Also, use ctor init lists, and you don't have to repeat template arguments inside the class (`Vector() : coords(n, 0.0f) {}`).

Comment: ... Is it possible to create templates that aren't based on types? This is kind of blowing my mind. Where can I read up on this?

Comment: I don't want always N zeros. If crds has other values than 0 it should assign them.

What do you mean my "sizes don't match"? If I make a vector full on zeros and it's size is dependant on the number of elements in crds, how won't they match?

Comment: @aardvarkk: Yes. 14.1.4 "A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualiﬁed) types: (...)"

Comment: @nils: Yes, I misread, sorry. That's still not a very good design.

Answer (score 2):

This does what I think you are asking for. The code complexity in the 2nd constructor ensures that we don't copy extra values in, just to erase them.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

// untested
template <std::size_t n>
struct Vector {
  std::vector<float> coords;
  Vector() : coords(n, 0.) {}
  Vector(const std::vector<float>& crds)
    : coords(crds.begin(),
        crds.begin()+std::min(n, crds.size())) {
    // resize() extends coords with 0.0 values
    coords.resize(n);
  }
};

int main () {
  std::vector<float> v(3);
  Vector<6> V(v);
  assert(V.coords.size() == 6);
}
```

---

**EDIT**: responding to explained requirements:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

// untested
template <std::size_t n>
struct Vector {
  std::vector<float> coords;
  Vector() : coords(n, 0.) {}
  Vector(const std::vector<float>& crds)
    : coords(crds) { }
};

int main () {
  Vector<6> V1;
  Vector<6> V2(std::vector<float>(3, 2.));
  Vector<6> V3(std::vector<float>(10, 3.));
  assert(V1.coords.size() == 6);
  assert(V2.coords.size() == 3);
  assert(V3.coords.size() == 10);
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Responding to requirement for initializer list.

If your compiler provides c++11 features, you can initialize either `std::vector` or `Vector`  from a list of values, using `std::initializer_list`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <initializer_list>

// untested
template <std::size_t n>
struct Vector {
  std::vector<float> coords;
  Vector() : coords(n, 0.) {}
  Vector(const std::vector<float>& crds)
    : coords(crds) { }
  Vector(std::initializer_list<float> list)
    : coords(list) {}

};

int main () {
  Vector<6> V1;
  Vector<6> V2(std::vector<float>(3, 2.));
  Vector<6> V3(std::vector<float>(10, 3.));
  Vector<6> V4(std::vector<float> ({1, 2, 3, 4}));
  Vector<6> V5({1, 2, 3, 4});
  assert(V1.coords.size() == 6);
  assert(V2.coords.size() == 3);
  assert(V3.coords.size() == 10);
  assert(V4.coords.size() == 4);
  assert(V5.coords.size() == 4);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to erase extra values. The default constructor makes a vector with 2 elements. The second constructor should make a vector with n elements. That means that if I want to make a vector with 10 elements I can use the second constructor to do it.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the requirements. I thought that `Vector<n>::coords` should always be of size `n`.

Comment: I should be able to set different values for the elements through the third constructor - that means if i do Vector<6> V3(std::vector<float>(5, 3,5,8,9,0)); it should make me a vector with the elements 3,5,8,9,0. This is my main problem - how to implement that.
Sorry, if my first description was bad to understand.

Comment: If looks like you are looking for initializer lists. See my edit above. Also, initializer lists are explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: yeah, that's the problem. I need to use vector STL in this code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correcly what you want to do, simply using standard vector constructors should do what you want:

```
#include <vector>

template <int N>
class Vector {
public:
  std::vector<float> coords;

  Vector ()
    : coords(N, 0.0f)
  {}

  Vector (const std::vector<float> & crds)
    : coords(crds)
  {}
};
```

But, as emphasized by others in the comments, this seems to be poorly designed (in particular, I fail to understand why the role of `N` in both constructors is so asymmetric)